# Artisan migration won't run in controller

Tags: php, json, laravel, rest, laravel-artisan

I have a DB of contacts which is populated via API /users, it works correctly collecting all users data into table.

I want the user to hit a button and get an updated contact list with unique value (phone and email)

To do this **I wish to run a migrate:refresh whenever the user hits the #getcontacts button**, so it gets a brand new list of contacts updated to the latest insert.

I still get

---

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry for key 'contacts_email_unique'

```
use Artisan

[...]



public function makeContacts(){

    $apiResponse = file_get_contents($this->userList); //call to the api URL

    $users = json_decode(
        $this->extractString($apiResponse,9,-1)
    ); //hard formatting response for my own purposes 

 Artisan::call('migrate:refresh', array('--path' => 'app/migrations', '--force' => true));

    foreach ($users as $user){ 

        $contact = new Contact(); 
        $contact->firstname = $user->firstname; 
        $contact->lastname = $user->lastname; 
        $contact->email = $user->email; 
        $contact->phone = $user->phone; 
        foreach ($user->zones->zones as $zone){
            $contact->zone = $zone->name;
        }
        $contact->save(); 

    }
}
```

I noticed that:

1. calling it at the very beginning of my function doesn't change anything
2. refresh command works perfectly if called from console
3. dumping result gives 0 (I don't know what does it means, actually)

What can I do to get rid of this problem? Where is my mistake? I can't really understand why it won't run the command. Syntax seems to be correct tho, thanks for the help!!

Comment: I think you are likely inserting the same set of email twice hence the reason for integrity constraint error. You have a duplicate entry for email. Why not check if an email exists before you insert?

Comment: That's the point! Refresh should empty my database everytime a user hits the button to get contacts instead seems like refresh wont run at all

Comment: That is true. try running php artisan migrate:refresh from console and see whether it works. If it doesn't, that could also be due to your mysql version

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing this out, i already tried it from console and it works

Comment: What is this??? `array('--path' => 'app/migrations', '--force' => true));` do you really need that? maybe that is why it doesn't work

Comment: It is necessary parameter for Artisan:call function, I can try with an empty array tho aaaaand it works, thank you a lot! If you can post the answer I can sign it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to lewis4u: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2502731/lewis4u

I used an empty array as second parameter of Artisan:call function and it works perfectly now.